# How to split unintentionally conjoined features into single parts at scale? [QGIS]

Tags: vector, splitting, multipart, singlepart

I have this layer of linear features which I produced from vectorising a raster image. The features in question are berry plantations that are more or less consistent lengths and widths, but some parallel plantation rows are connected so that two or more lines count as one feature. I need each line to be a separate polygon/feature so I can calculate their lengths. See the image for example.

I know I can split them with Edit features -> Split Geometry. However, there are so many of them (hundreds) that I was wondering if there might be a more automatized way of dealing with this problem.

[image: The red circles indicate unwanted bridges between the plantations]

Comment: Your problem description and image seem to address two different (and opposite) problems.

Comment: How so? I'm trying to remove the conjoined parts so each row can be converted into an independent feature. The image and description describe the same problem.

Comment: @Vince I don't think I agree. The linear features OP is describing are the green polygons, not the remaining visible strips of rasters visible in between. The bits circled in red are the bits of green polygon which cross over the underlying raster, OP wants these connecting bits gone. That being said, I can't think of a solution, sorry OP.

Comment: The title text asks to "split" features, but the image shows gaps that need to be *filled*.

Comment: Nowhere am I asking to fill gaps. The circles indicate the problem.

Comment: @Vince you're looking at the wrong thing mate. I saw it the same way as you at first. The thinner lines with different colour pixels are not the features that OP is talking about. It's the wider solid green polygons. The circles show where these polygons are connected, this is where OP wants to split them.